# Product of elements of a vector which has very large values and very low values ordered in decreasing order (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, vector

I have to compute the product of the elements in a vector V. The elements of my vector are in decreasing order and go from very large numbers (eg 5e^5) to very small numbers (e.g 1.8e^-8).

I am using MATLAB; if I do prod(V) I get infinity, while if I flip(V) and compute prod(V) I get zero. I imagine the problem is that matlab computes the product in order and once it gets a very large number gives infinity and when it gets a very low number gives 0.

To solve the problem I am thinking about reshuffling the elements in the vector so that I do the product of a big element on the top of the vector with a small element on the bottom. Namely the largest multiplied the lowest times the second largest with the second lowest and so on... How can I code this stuff efficiently?

I don't know if it is the best way to procede and if you know any other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on simply reshuffling array elements before using `prod` because (a) I don't expect MATLAB guarantees anything about the order in which it will multiply the elements and (b) the running product might nearly overflow or underflow, but not quite hit 0 or infinity, which could give you a severely inaccurate answer, but you won't have any way of knowing whether this happened.

You could do something like (untested code):

```
large = V(1:floor(numel(V)/2)); 
small = V(numel(large)+1:end);
large(end+1) = 1; % ensure large has at least as many elements as small
VProduct = 1;
for ii = 1:numel(small)
    VProduct = VProduct * large(ii) * small(ii);
    if VProduct < minValue || VProduct > maxValue % you must supply minValue and maxValue
        error('Inadequate precision')
    end
end
```

However a much more reliable solution would be to use arbitrary-precision arithmetic - one option is the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/numbers-and-precision.html), or you could look at [this File Exchange contribution](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class).